# Custom YUI Carousel

Tags: javascript, yui, carousel

I want to create custom carousel from YUI 2.9

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/csl_selection_clean.html

In this I want to hide yui carousel nav items , not next and previous buttons.

I can achieve this using CSS, But is there any property available in YUI 2.9?

hideNavigation or somehting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation code for [Carosel.js](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/Carousel.js.html) appears to require that `numVisible > 0`  The numVisible parameter is used throughout the code, so it seems like your best bet is to go ahead with the CSS plan  and hide the nav items.

```
_validateNumVisible: function (val) {
    var rv = false;

    if (JS.isNumber(val)) {
        rv = val > 0 && val <= this.get("numItems");
    } else if (JS.isArray(val)) {
        if (JS.isNumber(val[0]) && JS.isNumber(val[1])) {
            rv = val[0] * val[1] > 0 && val.length == 2;
        }
    }

    return rv;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for technical reason to use css to hide that carousle nav